# Difference between JavaScript Array every and some

Tags: javascript, arrays

I see both return true or false upon given tests.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

What should be the right case to use them both together ?

Test code:

```js
function checkUsersValid(goodUsers) {
  return function allUsersValid(submittedUsers) {
    //Im testing arrays here
    return submittedUsers.every(function isBigEnough(element, index, array) {
   return goodUsers.some(function (el, i, arr) {
    return element.id == el.id;
   });
 });
  };
}

var goodUsers = [
      { id: 1 },
      { id: 2 },
      { id: 3 }
    ];
    
var testAllValid = checkUsersValid(goodUsers);

testAllValid([
      { id: 2 },
      { id: 1 }
    ]);
```

Comment: Please provide the code you used and explain what happened and what you would have expected to happen. It is perfectly possible for both of these to return true

Comment: added code into post

Answer (score 66, accepted):

(If you know C# LINQ , it's like `Any` vs `All`)

- `some` will return true if *any* predicate is `true`
- `every` will return true if *all* predicate is `true`

Where predicate means function that returns `bool` ( true/false) for each element

`every` returns on first `false`.
`some` returns on first `true`

Comment: @PavelGatnar Where did you see that I told him he should know LINQ? I said `_if_` , for as reference example in another language. Also my explanation explain it  pretty clear  -  without knowing C#.

Comment: didn't get it. If both methods immediately returns false for first falsy occurrence. what is the difference between both?? every() method should iterate all the element till end and then return.

Comment: @Aarvy `every` returns on first `false`. `some` returns on first `true`

Comment: Btw why names are every and some ? It should be any and all , as they are much more clearer. Was it something that might break existing website ?

Comment: @sktguha see this answer below, makes sense imo https://stackoverflow.com/a/31809738/2632129

Answer (score 21):

`some` is analogue to logical `or`
`every` is analogue to logical `and`

logically `every` implies `some`, but not in reverse

try this:

```
var identity = function(x){return x}
console.log([true, true].some(identity))//true
console.log([true, true].every(identity))//true
console.log([true, false].some(identity))//true
console.log([true, false].every(identity))//false
console.log([false, false].some(identity))//false
console.log([false, false].every(identity))//false
console.log([undefined, true].some(identity))//true
console.log([undefined, true].every(identity))//false
console.log([undefined, false].some(identity))//false
console.log([undefined, false].every(identity))//false
console.log([undefined, undefined].some(identity))//false
console.log([undefined, undefined].every(identity))//false
```

Comment: I'm not the downviter but I think you should add the actual result of the console log : example : `console.log(1+1)//2` . +1 btw

Comment: It is an excellent explanation and the easiest way to remember. +1

Answer (score 6):

The documentation answers your question...

> The **some()** method tests whether some element in the array passes the
>   test implemented by the provided function.
>
> The **every()** method tests whether all elements in the array pass the
>   test implemented by the provided function.

So you will use them, according if you want to test `some` elements or `every` elements.

If `every() returns true` then `some() returns true`.

but

If `some() returns true` then `we cannot conclude anything about the result of every()`.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.some` is good if you are looking for an intruder or a relic, meaning you only need to know if there is one at least that satisfies your constraints.

`Array.prototy.every` on the other hand is useful to check the integrity of an array, for example, "Are all items of my array an instance of `Car`?".

Answer (score 2):

### Summary:

- Use `Array.prototype.some` to find out if one particular element in the array matches a boolean condition.
- Use `Array.prototype.every` to find out if all elements in the array matches a boolean condition.

### Example:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const evenArr = [2, 4, 6];

const even = (element) => {
  return element % 2 === 0;
};

console.log(array.some(even));    // true
console.log(array.every(even))    // false
console.log(evenArr.every(even))  // true
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple example of Array.prototype.every():**
The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Note: This method returns true for any condition put on an empty array.

```
function lessThanTwenty(currentValue) {
  return currentValue < 20;
}

let array = [1, 30, 39, 29, 10, 19];

console.log(array.every(lessThanTwenty));

//output : false
```

**Simple example of Array.prototype.some():**

The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

Note: This method returns false for any condition put on an empty array.

```
let array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let even = function(ele) { 
  return ele % 2 === 0;
};

console.log(array.some(even));
// output: true
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Let me tell you a secret.....

## They are both the same*

One is just a negated version of the other. We have both because we can. And it's super convenient.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const lte5 = value => value <= 5 // Less than or Equal

const every = arr.every(v => lte5(v))
const some = !arr.some(v => !lte5(v))

console.log('Are they same?', every === some)
```

### Read with me:

> "With an array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, ...

#### 1) `every`

> ... It is *true* that '***every*** item is smaller than or equal 5'."

#### 2) `some`

> ... It is *not true* that '**some** item is *not* smaller than or equal 5'."

---

To disprove the first statement, we need to find at least one (or "*some*") item for which the condition is not true. Hence this is why `every` returns `false` and bails when the first item **fails**. It will, however, go through the whole array if all **pass** the condition.

To disprove the second statement, we need to verify that "every" item **does not** pass the condition. Hence this is why `some` returns `true` and bails when the first item **passes**. It will, however, go through the whole array if all **fail** the condition.

---

In the following snippet, notice that both `every` and `some` run four times, that is until the end of the array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const lte5 = value => value <= 5

console.log('Checking that every item is smaller than or equal 5.')
const every = arr.every((v, ix) => {
    const result = lte5(v)
    console.log(`${ix}: is`, v, '<= 5 ?', result)
    return result
})

console.log('is every item <= 5 ?', every)

console.log('Checking that some item is larger than 5. (i.e. NOT smaller than or equal 5)')
const some = arr.some((v, ix) => {
    const result = !lte5(v)
    console.log(`${ix}: is`, v, '> 5 ?', result)
    return result
})

console.log('is some item > 5', some)
console.log('is every item <= 5 ?', !some)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every Method: If all array elements fulfill our condition , it returns true.
Some Method: If one or more array elements fulfill our condition, it returns false.
It's very simple.

```js
// Every & Some
const num1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const num2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];

const everyMethod = num1.every(myFunction);
const sumMethod = num1.some(myFunction);

function myFunction(value) {
    return value > 3;
}
console.log(everyMethod);//Retun false
console.log(sumMethod);//Return True
```