# Checking Every Input and Disabling a Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have a button and I want to disable it when any of the input field is empty.

Below is not working. If all input fields are empty, it returns true which is correct. But if only one input field is filled, it returns false which is not correct. It should return true until all fields are filled.

```
<Button
  disabled={Object.values(values).every(x => x === "")}
  onClick={handleSubmit}>
  Submit
</Button>
```

Below is working correctly but `ESlint` throws an error.

```
<Button
  disabled={Object.values(values).every(function () {
    for (let key in values) {
      if (values[key] === "")
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  })}
  onClick={handleSubmit}>
  Submit
</Button>
```

`ESlint` error:

`for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which is virtually never what you want. Use Object.{keys,values,entries}, and iterate over the resulting array  no-restricted-syntax`

How can I correct `disabled` functionality?

`values={{ testData1: '', testData2: '', testData3: ''}}`

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion from ESLint?

Comment: *If any value is not empty, it returns false but I need if all values are empty it should return true.* Both mean the same thing. Could you explain when the button should be disabled? and add the structure of `values` to the question

Comment: Explained better. Please see the question. Also added the `values`.

Comment: @ilvthsgm, Could you try changing `every` to `some` if you need to have all the fields as required. Like `disabled={Object.values(values).some(x => x === "")}`

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Awesome, that worked. If you could write an answer, I will accept it. Also If you could tell the difference in your answer(`every` vs `some`), that would be even better.

Comment: @ilvthsgm, Posted as an answer along with explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change,

`disabled={Object.values(values).every(x => x === "")}`

**To:**

`disabled={Object.values(values).some(x => x === "")}`

**Reason for the change:**

The [**every**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method checks whether all elements in the array pass the test.

> So in your case, using `every` checks if all the value is empty,
> and as you told that initial state it was working (on load) because on
> initial render all the value will be empty and hence this test pass (and returns true)
> but once you have any value it will return false because it has one of
> the value.

Whereas [**Some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on the other hand, checks whether at least one of the element in the array pass the test.

> Here we need to use `some` because it will check whether at least one
> of the value is empty or not. It will return true till all the values
> are filled. If all the fields are filled then it will return false.

[More on difference between every and some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31809727/7785337)

Answer (score 2):

`Object.values(values)` returns an array, so you can iterate over it with `for..of`.

Below code is equivalent to yours (assuming values is a flat object) but uses `for..of` instead of `for..in`, and thus should look fine to ESlint eyes:

```html
<Button
  disabled={function () {
    for (const val of Object.values(values)) {
        if (val === "")
            return true;
    }
    return false;
    }}
  onClick={handleSubmit}>
  Submit
</Button>
```

---

Edit: this snippet should work for nested objects:

```html
<Button
    disabled={
        function findEmpty(arg) {

            for (i in arg) {
                if (typeof arg[i] === 'object') {
                    return findEmpty(arg[i]);
                }

                if (arg[i] == "") {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false
        }
        findEmpty(values);
    }
    onClick={handleSubmit}>
    Submit
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. TS throws following error with your approach: `Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.
  Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type 'true'.` However If I change my type from `readonly disabled?: boolean;` to `readonly disabled?: any;`, `disabled` functionality does not work.

Comment: I just saw the update on your question, is values an object inside an object? If so that's the issue.

Comment: That is correct. It's nested objects. How can I correct this without changing the `values`?

Comment: I edited the answer, try with the 2nd snippet (I wrote plain js, so you should still see type errors if you parse it with TS).

Comment: 2nd snippet has no error but it always returns `false`.

Comment: Would you mind pasting here a mockup of your values object so that I have something to test? The one in the question is not a valid js object (nested objects need a label).

Comment: `<Formik initialValues={{ comments: '', dateEnd: '', dateStart: '' }}>` and if I `console.log('values:: ', values)` it is `values::  – {comments: "", dateEnd: "", dateStart: ""}`

Comment: Then it's not a nested object... it's just enclosed in braces because it's html. This object is handled properly by the first snippet in my answer...

Comment: You are right, sorry. First snippet has TS error. I am working on that error, then I will accept your answer.

Comment: Haven't tried this yet, but maybe writing `disabled={function () : boolean | undefined {` could solve the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not worked.